# right-align the amounts in a text using `jq`, avoiding `if-then-else`

Tags: jq, text-processing, text-alignment

I would like to right-align the amounts in a text using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```bash
INPUT='
# comment
lorem ipsum

* Header
2022-01-01 Internet
    provider       30.00 EUR
    router          5.00 EUR
2022-01-01 House
    rent       321.00 EUR
    carports    20.00 EUR, 20.00 EUR
'
```

I came up with a solution, bit it looks a bit too lengthy for me - is there a more concise solution that avoids `if-then-else`?

```bash
jq --raw-input --raw-output --argjson alignToColumn 40 '
  "\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR" as $searchPattern |
  if test($searchPattern)
  then match($searchPattern) as $match |
       sub($searchPattern;
           " " * ($alignToColumn - $match.offset - $match.length) +
           $match.string)
  else .
  end
' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```
# comment
lorem ipsum

* Header
2022-01-01 Internet
    provider                   30.00 EUR
    router                      5.00 EUR
2022-01-01 House
    rent                      321.00 EUR
    carports                   20.00 EUR, 20.00 EUR
```

Comment: That's not JSON, why would you do this with JQ?

Comment: Because jq is not only useful for processing json.
Take a look at the answer of @pmf: Just 3 lines of code.
What more concise solution do you suggest?

Comment: The ability to read non-JSON input is to support the *creation* of JSON, though. If you aren't using JSON for either input or output, there are better tools to use.

Comment: What does "better" mean in this context?
So far, the shortest solution that meets all the requirements is @pmf's jq code.
Why not use jq for text processing if it can do that with flying colours?
The argument "because there are better tools" sounds weak to me when I compare the below awk solution with the jq solution. Both tools work great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `if … then … else … end` by using the alternative operator `//`.

```bash
"\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR" as $searchPattern | (match($searchPattern) as $m
  | .[:$m.offset] + ($alignToColumn - $m.offset - $m.length) * " " + .[$m.offset:]
) // .
```

```
# comment
lorem ipsum

* Header
2022-01-01 Internet
    provider                   30.00 EUR
    router                      5.00 EUR
2022-01-01 House
    rent                      321.00 EUR
    carports                   20.00 EUR, 20.00 EUR
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iQ_pVd3WFUM)

Comment: This solution won't work on input lines with too many spaces before the EUR amounts, e.g.`    car ports                                20.00 EUR, 20.00 EUR`

Answer (score 2):

Use `capture`, `//`, and

```
def lpad($len): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
```

For example:

```
jq -Rr --argjson aligntocolumn 40 '
  def lpad($len): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
  (capture("(?<a>^.*?) *(?<b>\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR.*)$")
   | ($aligntocolumn - (.a|length)) as $l
  | "\(.a)\(.b|lpad($l))") // .
'
```

Notice the use of the "reluctant" (non-greedy) quantifier: `*?`

Answer (score 0):

The motivation for using `jq` was "it provides concise solutions to this problem". [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) does too:

```
awk -vALIGN=40 'match($0, /[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\s+EUR/) {
  $0 = sprintf(\
    "%s%"(ALIGN-RSTART)"s%s",
    substr($0, 1, RSTART-1),
    substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH),
    substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH))
}
{print}' input
```

Since this is text-processing, we don't need to deal with jq's syntax and can use tools specfically built for this job.

Output:

```
# comment
lorem ipsum

* Header
2022-01-01 Internet
    provider                  30.00 EUR
    router                     5.00 EUR
2022-01-01 House
    rent                     321.00 EUR
    carports                  20.00 EUR, 20.00 EUR
```

The above script was written and tested with *GNU Awk (5.1.0)*, available in most GNU+Linux distributions. Unfortunately, it does not work with every version of awk.

To make the script work with mawk (version 1.3.4), the match regex must be changed to `match($0, /[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*[ \t]+EUR/)` – `\s` seems to be unsupported. It might also be possible to replace the character groups with `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:space:]]`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your `awk` solution. It is educational for me to compare the jq and awk solution with each other

Comment: @knittle - awk is fine, but your solution as posted is not very portable.  I've tried with various awks and at best the result is a syntax error related to the newline after the sprintf line, and at worst the wrong result.  Notably, I've tried an awk that identifies itself as "awk version 20200816"; and a GNU awk which describes itself as: GNU Awk 5.2.0, API 3.2, PMA Avon 7, (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p13, GNU MP 6.2.1)

Comment: @peak thanks for testing. The line break was added only when posting here, it wasn't part of my original script (which was a single line only). I added it to increase readability, but instead broke the script. Fixing the newline (escaping, or moving the first parameter up) fixes the script again. I tried with GNU Awk 5.1.0. Can you tell me more about the "wrong result"?

Comment: awk version 20200816 (on a mac) simply echoes the input.  Obviously a highly portable version using awk is possible, but the point is that it's easy to be lured into using some neat-but-not-so-portable feature.

Comment: The mawk implementation (https://invisible-island.net/mawk/) also just echoes the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short and simple solution (no non-greedy regex quantifiers) that is also both efficient and generic (it does not assume anything about the number of spaces before the EUR amounts):

```
jq -Rr --argjson aligntocolumn 40 '
  def lpad($len): $s | tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
  ( match("(?<b> *\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR.*)$") as $m
    | .[:.$m.offset] + ($m.string | sub("^ *";"") | lpad($aligntocolumn - $m.offset)) // .
'
```